# Should I be using InnoDB for this?

Tags: sql, mysql, transactions, innodb

I am developing a personal PHP/MySQL app, and I came across this particular scenario in my project:

I have various comment threads. This is handled by two tables - 'Comments' and 'Threads', with each comment in 'Comments' table having a 'thread_id' attribute indicating which thread the comment belongs to. When the user deletes a comment thread, currently I am doing two separate DELETE SQL queries:

1. First delete all the comments belonging to the thread in the 'Comments' table
2. Then, clearing the thread record from the 'Threads' table.

I also have another situation, where I need to insert data from a form into two separate tables.

Should I be using transactions for these kind of situations? If so, is it a general rule of thumb to use transactions whenever I need to perform such multiple SQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your actual needs, transactions are just a way of ensuring that all data manipulation that forms a single transaction gets executed successfully, and that transactions happen sequentially (a new transaction cannot be made until the previous one has either succeeded or failed). If one of the queries fails for whatever reason, the whole transaction will fail and the previous state will be restored.

If you absolutely need to make sure that no threads will be deleted unless all the comments have been deleted beforehand, go for transactions. If you need all the speed you can get, go for MyISAM

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a general rule of thumb to use transactions when doing multiple operations that are related. If you do switch to InnoDB (usually a good idea, but not always. We didn't really discuss any requirements besides transactions, so I won't comment more), I'd also suggest setting a constraint on Comments that points to Threads as it sounds like a comment must be assigned to a thread. Deleting the thread would then remove associated comments in a single atomic statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ACID transactions, you want InnoDB.  If having one DELETE succeed and the other fail means having to manually DELETE the failed attempt, I'd say that's a hardship better handled with the database.  Those situations call for transactions.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question I would recommend declaring thread_id as a foreign key in your comments table.  This should reference the id column of the thread table.  You can then set 'ON DELETE CASCADE' this means that when the ID is removed from the thread table all comments that reference that ID will also be deleted.